Bittensor Subtensor Chain
Does anyone know how to run a public subtensor node and synchronize with Bittensor network on nakamoto instead of the current finney ? There are some nodes currently running on nakamoto chain.
I am using current subtensor repo https://github.com/opentensor/subtensor?tab=readme-ov-file
